# How to use AFNetworking iOS library to login to sharepoint?

Tags: ios, sharepoint, afnetworking

I want to use iOS AFNetworking library to login to sharepoint server and use rest svc services from my iOS app. But I don't have any appropriate example to go with it.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands demos, https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Did you ever get anything working to login into Sharepoint?  I am trying to login to a Sharepoint 2013 server.